# Understanding bash *String* comparison

Tags: bash

I'm trying to compare version numbers. For example, if 10.9 is less than 10.11.

Can someone please explain why this doesn't print 'yes'?

```
 if [[ "9" < "10" ]]; then echo yes; fi
```

What do I need to do to make this work correctly as clearly, 9 should be less than 10?

In addition, if I have "10.9" in a variable $VERSION, how would this be compared with "10.11", as this also fails to print 'yes'

```
if [[ $VERSION < "10.11" ]]; then echo yes; fi
```

Answer (score 2):

In this case, this will return the correct answer

```
if [[ "8" < "9" ]]; then echo yes; fi
```

But for your specific case  "10" is less than "9" because 1 is less than 9.
String comparison works different than numeric, so the order will be something like that

1

10

20

21

3

...

You can convert your string to numeric and use the `-lt` (less than) operator for numeric values. Bash values are untyped so, this will work

```
if [ "9" -lt "10" ]; then echo yes; fi
```

Some Bash reference can be found [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html)

Be aware that "10.9" lt isn't working with a float. You can use an awk comparison for this.

```
if [ -n "10.1" -a -n "10.2" ]; then echo yes; fi
```

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Having played around trying to get it to work, I missed the quotes. This is string comparison, so -lt doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense, though I receive a version number as a string variable, how would I convert that to a numeric. As mentioned in my question, the version is "10.9" compared with "10.11".

Comment: Simply use -lt :) answer edited

Comment: That's fine to say with integers, but doesn't work with floats. Where $VERSION is a string, this fails: **if [[ $VERSION -lt 10.11 ]]; then echo yes; fi**

Comment: This is because you have a dot. In comparison you have to use a comma. Dot is a meta character

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83732/discussion-between-vargan-and-thedarkknight).

Comment: The dot is only a special character in a regular expression (the right-hand operand to the `=~` operator). Here, it's just another character in a string.

Comment: You're right chepner, modifying my answer

Answer (score 1):

Since `<` is a *string* comparison operator, `"9"` is lexicographically *greater* than `"10"`. `bash` can only compare integers (using `-lt`, in which case `[ "9" -lt "10 ]` would be true. (Note that `bash` does not have separate string and integer types, only strings, meaning `"9"` and `9` are the exact same string. It's the operator, not the operands, that determine the behavior.)

`bash` does not work with floating point values at all. You need to use an external command (such as `bc` or `awk`) to compare them. Of course, if your version numbers can contain more than 1 decimal point, then you'll need to use some other approach, since they are no longer floating point numbers.

Comment: I was a bit premature in thinking this works. When $VERSION is 10.9 or 10.12, they both output 'yes'.

Comment: I overlooked how `bc` works. It outputs a 1=true, 0=false string; the exit status is independent of the result of the comparison.

Comment: Comparing **bc <<< "10.9 < 10.11"** with **bc <<< "10.12 < 10.11"**, they both return 0

Comment: Ugh. I don't use `bc` often; this might be the POSIX behavior I mentioned. In any case, the point is you need to use *some* other program (`awk` is another option). If your version numbers have more than one decimal point, then what you use to compare floating point values is a moot point, of course.